# uniq treats lines as if they were different but they are ostensibly the same

Tags: command-line, text-processing, uniq

I created and edited a file with vi called sort.txt which looks like this:

```
sentence one 
sentence two
sentence one
sentence three
sentence two
sentence two
sentence three
sentence one
sentence two
sentence one
sentence one
sentence one
sentence three
sentence four
sentence five
```

When I do `sort sort.txt | uniq -c`   I get this:

```
  1 sentence five
  1 sentence four
  5 sentence one
  1 sentence one 
  3 sentence three
  4 sentence two
```

In addition, when I write `sort sort.txt | uniq -u`, "sentence one" also appears there.
I don't understand why "sentence one" appears twice as if the content were different, could someone explain why?

Comment: Do `cat -A` or `hexdump -C` on the file. Perhaps there's non-printable characters in that one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have trailing whitespace at the end of the first `sentence one`:

```
$ cat -et sort.txt
sentence one $
sentence two$
sentence one$
sentence three$
sentence two$
sentence two$
sentence three$
sentence one$
sentence two$
sentence one$
sentence one$
sentence one$
sentence three$
sentence four$
sentence five$
```